# How to align radio button horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have radio button input with label, however I cannot align them horizontally, it just appeared one by one vertically, how can I make it align one by one horizontally.

```
<div class="cc-selector-2" align="right">
       {{range $index,$url := .Avatars}}                                            
         <label for="pic1">                                                                  
         <input type="radio" name="avatar" id={{$url}} value={{$url}} />               
         <img src={{$url}} alt="" height="40" width="40"/>                                                                                                   
         </label>
         {{end}}
 </div>

 <style>      
.cc-selector-2 input{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
}

    label {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        font-size: .85em;
        background-color:buttonface;
    }

 </style>
```

Comment: put complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with display: inline-block ;)

```css
cc-selector-2{
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:auto;
  font-size: .85em;
  background-color:buttonface; 
}

input {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc-selector-2" align="right">
    <label for="pic1">
      <input type="radio" name="avatar" id={{$url}} value={{$url}} />          
      <img src={{$url}} alt="" height="40" width="40"/>
    </label>
    <label for="pic1">
      <input type="radio" name="avatar" id={{$url}} value={{$url}} />          
      <img src={{$url}} alt="" height="40" width="40"/>
    </label>
</div>
```